# Error on UnprocessableEntityException in Nest.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

Im fairly new to nest.js and following along a tutorial which you can see here:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/build-web-apis-with-nestjs-beginners-guide/

So Im building the validate.pipe.ts and Im getting an error on the following code.

```js
import { Injectable, ArgumentMetadata, BadRequestException, ValidationPipe, UnprocessableEntityException } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class ValidateInputPipe extends ValidationPipe {
   public async transform(value, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
      try {
        return await super.transform(value, metadata);
      } catch (e) {
         if (e instanceof BadRequestException) {
            throw new UnprocessableEntityException(this.handleError(e.message.message));
         }
      }
   }

   private handleError(errors) {
    return errors.map(error => error.constraints);
   }
}
```

This is my code above and my error is

```
Property 'message' does not exist on type 'string'.

throw new UnprocessableEntityException(this.handleError(e.message.message));
```

Answer (score 1):

I passed the e straight in and that seemed to fix the problem

````
} catch (e) {
         if (e instanceof BadRequestException) {
            throw new UnprocessableEntityException(e);
         }
      }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

it should be

> e.message

not e.message.message in the below line

```
        throw new UnprocessableEntityException(this.handleError(e.message.message));
```

Comment: Which i tired but then the .map here becomes not a function

return errors.map(error => error.constraints);

Comment: I thought so too, but there must be something more wrong here in this tutorial's code because `handleError` assumes its argument to be an _array_ of errors, it seems. Check the code in the linked tutorial.